# Code add button SMS Whatsapp and email

Tags: button, share

I several weeks try to add button SMS Whatsapp and email in WP theme but I have errors.

```
window.open(link, 'sharer', 'top=' + winTop + ',left=' + winLeft + ',toolbar=0,status=0,width='+winWidth+',height='+winHeight);
}

function eh_get_fburl(title, descr, url){
  return 'http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=' +encodeURIComponent(url)+ '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(title);
}

function eh_get_twurl(title, url){
  return 'http://twitter.com/home?status=' + encodeURIComponent(title) + '+' + encodeURIComponent(url);
}

function eh_get_gpurl(url){
  return 'https://plus.google.com/share?url=' + encodeURIComponent(url);
}

function eh_get_lnurl(title, url){
  return 'http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(title);
}

function eh_get_waurl(title, url){
  return 'whatsapp CODE' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(title);
}

function eh_get_txurl(title, url){
  return 'SMS CODE' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(title);
}

function eh_get_emurl(title, url){
  return 'Email CODE" + title + "&body=' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(title);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for whatsapp:

```
return "whatsapp://send?text="+encodeURIComponent(url)+" "+encodeURIComponent(title)
```

for sms:

```
return "sms:my_phone_number?body="+encodeURIComponent(url)+" "+encodeURIComponent(title)
```

for email:

```
return "mailto:?subject="+encodeURIComponent(title)+ "&body="+encodeURIComponent(url)+" "+encodeURIComponent(title)
```